# How can I get use input to create a file within a program

Tags: c, user-input

I am currently using a software dev. tool kit for a camera. I am able to take a pictur with this camera and save it as a bmp, but I have to hard-code the file name within the script. 
The camera uses the file name I now hard code as an element for a structure that it uses as an argument for its save function.

Example:

```
imageparam.filename = L"hardcodefilename.bmp";
```

I would like a user to be able to type a file name, and have that name inserted into the above example. I am having a hard time getting around the quotes that are used in the code. Is there any way to use `getline()` or `scanf()` and have its input feed in between those quotes?

Note: I've only been using C for a few weeks, so please be kind if the solution is obvious.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact interaction scenario you're looking for here: with any available input routine (scanf, gets, ..._ you can get `hardcodefilename.bmp` if that's what the user types, if not `hardcodefilename.bmp` could be passed as a command line parameter, eg `yourutility --filename=hardcodefilename.bmp`  using getopt.  It might be useful to add the exact scenario you are thinking about.

Comment: The answer would depend upon what software is provided with the development environment for the camera.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to add the quotes around the user entries ??

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way is to pass as arguments to the main function. So in Visual Studio, you just pass as command line arguments. In that fashion, you always can give the user control to save a file name.